# How do I write this complex IF formula in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Cell:

- E13 is a `YES` or `NO`,
- E14 is a number,
- L21 is a currency amount equal to E14*1 BUT;

  - If cell E13 is `YES`, then cell L21 cannot be any higher than $80.00;
  - If cell E13 is `NO`, then cell L21 cannot be any higher than $40.00.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please add more detail to clarify your question. In its current form it may be deleted.

Comment: @RandolphWest The question seems pretty straightforward. What other details are necessary?

Comment: Jerry's edit would be what I was getting at.

Answer (score 3):

If E13 can only be Yes or No, you can use this:

```
=IF(E13="Yes",MIN(E14,80),MIN(E14,40))
```

If E13 is `Yes`, get the lower of E14 and 80, otherwise, the lower of E14 and 40.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(E13="yes",IF(E14>80,80,E14),IF(E14>40,40,E14))

Might not be elegant, e.g. doesn't discriminate between "no" and not "yes", but it works.